# How can I solve Video Rating Disabled?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm doing a project using the YouTube Data API's [`Videos.rate`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) endpoint.

And I got some problems: some particular minor channels (e.g. my client's channel) are sending error messages:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The owner of the video that you are trying to rate has disabled ratings for that video.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The owner of the video that you are trying to rate has disabled ratings for that video.",
                "domain": "youtube.video",
                "reason": "videoRatingDisabled",
                "location": "id",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
```

My boss wants to help them to solve that problem, but I don't know how to solve this at all. There is no problem with other major channels with 1M+ subscriptions.

I did my best to google this problem, yet couldn't find good results until now.

Answer (score 0):

Before rating the video, check if the vide has enabled the rating.

I can't test right now, but, and idea could be:

- Use [getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) and check the **`items[].rating`** value - if the result is **`none`** or **`unspecified`**, then, you have to handle your logic for make them know that this video can't be rated  - due its owner disabled rating their video.

The message you show in your question says that you cannot rate that video because the owner doesn't allow it. YouTube Data API wont bypass such restriction and there's not much that can be done further.

Ask your boss (*or the owner of the video*) about allow rating their video(s) and then verify if the video can be rated, if so, try again rate the video.

Comment: A strange thing is, I also have this error, but if I go to YouTube, I can "like" this video. There's just not the number of like/dislike displayed. But I can still can like the video myself and have it to my favorites videos. So why not being able to "rate" it as liked with the API ? Strange thing...

Comment: @blackarcanis maybe they (*YouTube*) have different rules for their API and the website itself. Consider post your in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) and so they may give more information about it.